# Laravel 8 HTTP Client - Como enviar un string dentro del cuerpo de solicitud POST

Tags: laravel, api, string, post

Buen día, necesito enviar una solicitud POST a una API que requiere como parámetro una cadena de texto o String. Estoy utilizando HTTP Client de Laravel para realizar las solicitudes, pero el formato de cuerpo `data` es un array.

```
$response = Http::acceptJson()->withHeaders([
                'Connection' => 'keep-alive',
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
            ])->post('https://example.com/endpoint', [ "NtpcFQj9lQQoWuztFpssFoSQTAwbGReBbl6nc4HKYLEm" ]);
```

Función `post()` del archivo `Illuminate\Http\Client\PendingRequest`

```
/**
     * Issue a POST request to the given URL.
     *
     * @param  string  $url
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Client\Response
     */
    public function post(string $url, array $data = [])
    {
        return $this->send('POST', $url, [
            $this->bodyFormat => $data,
        ]);
    }
```

Este es el formato de la solicitud haciendo un `Http::dd()` antes de enviar la request.

```
^ Illuminate\Http\Client\Request {#1381 ▼
  #request: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request {#1378 ▼
    -method: "POST"
    -requestTarget: null
    -uri: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri {#1366 ▶}
    -headers: array:6 [▼
      "Content-Length" => array:1 [▶]
      "User-Agent" => array:1 [▶]
      "Host" => array:1 [▶]
      "Accept" => array:1 [▼
        0 => "application/json"
      ]
      "Connection" => array:1 [▼
        0 => "keep-alive"
      ]
      "Content-Type" => array:1 [▼
        0 => "application/json"
      ]
    ]
    -headerNames: array:6 [▶]
    -protocol: "1.1"
    -stream: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream {#1369 ▶}
  }
  #data: array:1 [▼
    0 => "NtpcFQj9lQQoWuztFpssFoSQTAwbGReBbl6nc4HKYLEm"
  ]
}
```

Lo que necesito es que el `data` tenga el siguiente formato:

```
^ Illuminate\Http\Client\Request {#1381 ▼
  #request: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request {#1378 ▼
    -method: "POST"
    -requestTarget: null
    -uri: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Uri {#1366 ▶}
    -headers: array:6 [▼
      "Content-Length" => array:1 [▶]
      "User-Agent" => array:1 [▶]
      "Host" => array:1 [▶]
      "Accept" => array:1 [▼
        0 => "application/json"
      ]
      "Connection" => array:1 [▼
        0 => "keep-alive"
      ]
      "Content-Type" => array:1 [▼
        0 => "application/json"
      ]
    ]
    -headerNames: array:6 [▶]
    -protocol: "1.1"
    -stream: GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream {#1369 ▶}
  }
  #data: "NtpcFQj9lQQoWuztFpssFoSQTAwbGReBbl6nc4HKYLEm"
  ]
}
```

Intente cambiar el Content-Type a "text/plain" pero el string siempre se mantiene dentro del array. De esta forma:

```
#data: array:1 [▼
    "NtpcFQj9lQQoWuztFpssFoSQTAwbGReBbl6nc4HKYLEm" => 0
  ]
```

¿Alguna solución para enviar solo un string dentro del `data` con HTTP Client? ¿Otra librería de PHP que pueda usar para realizar solicitudes POST con un parámetro de tipo string?

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: usa [CURL](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php)

Comment: En la documentación está explicado [Request Data](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client#request-data) > *...para enviar datos adicionales con su solicitud, estos métodos aceptan una matriz de datos como su segundo argumento. De forma predeterminada, los datos se enviarán utilizando el tipo de contenido `application/json`*.

Comment: Y en el ejemplo que ponen muestra como construir el array con sus correspondientes claves/valores de forma que se codifiquen a json. Entonces, si quieres enviar un json como este `{ "name": "Steve", "role": "Network Administrator"}`, construyes un array como este `[ 'name' => 'Steve', 'role' => 'Network Administrator' ]`.